# A select JPA query that ignores the related entities of one-to-many relation, is that possible?

Tags: rest, jpa, one-to-many, createquery

I am new in JPA, so excuse me if my question seems basic.
I have an entity called User, which is related to a list of other entities like follow:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL , mappedBy = "user")
private List<session> sessionList;
```

In a controller class, I defined a find method in a RESTFull manner like follow:

```
@GET
@Path("/Users")
@Produces("application/json")
public List<UserDevice> findAllUsers()
{
    return em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u").getResultList();
}
```

The returned result contains all the sessions of the users which is normal, but make the result huge though I just want to retrieve the basic information of the users (all the simple columns).
My question is: is it possible to ignore the related entities and just keep the columns of the actual entity? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you explicitely map the association as eagerly loaded (using `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`), the above query should only return the fields of the users, and should not load their `sessionList`.

If the sessions are loaded, then the association is marked as eagerly loaded, or you load them lazily by calling a method of the `List<Session>`.

Comment: Perhaps the @Produces("application/json") uses reflection to serialize the object with all its relations to json, and thus initializes the lazy collection?

Comment: Thanks Rasmus and JB, Thank you very much for your answer, It working now after that I added FetchType.LAZY to the @OneToMany annotation :)

Comment: Rasmus, can you please explain what is reflection? Thank you

Comment: Thank you JB I will have a look to it

Comment: It seems that my problem now is with @ManyToOne relation, the lazy fetch of these relations is not working. I am searching for a solution of this problem but so far nothing is working. any suggestion?

Comment: *"Nothing is working"* is the poorest description you might give of a problem. Ask another question where you explain what you want to do, how you do it, what you expect it does, and what it does instead.

Comment: OK JB, excuse me! I will post a new question and describe more in details the problem... maybe I do not understand well my problem that is why my description is poor.

Comment: Ok, adding @XmlTransient as annotation to the method that gets the List<Session> resolve the problem. Apparently I have a name collision in the Session class. In this class I have a field called user and a getter of this field, so I guess there is a collision between this field and the get property: getSessionList().